# Delete value stored in attribute

Tags: swift

I kinda am lost and stuck with this and in need of help.

Lets say I got two view controllers, in View Controller #1 I have a login page, and the user logins normally through VC#1, and in View controller #2 i have a label which I want to display the username that was input in VC#1.

It is working for me however it shows the first username I put, and not the most recent one. So my question is, how do I clear the username that was input into the username so it doesnt store more than 1.

```
@IBAction func btnLogin(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if (txtUsername.text == "")
    {
        //Show Error Message
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Empty Field"
        alert.message = "Please enter your username"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Okay")
        alert.show()
    }
    else if (txtPassword.text == "")
    {
        //Show Error Message
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Empty Field"
        alert.message = "Please enter your password"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Okay")
        alert.show()
    }
    else
    {


        let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Members")

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", txtUsername.text!)


        let results:NSArray =  try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)

        if results.count > 0
        {
            let res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject

            txtUsername.text = res.valueForKey("username") as? String
            txtPassword.text = res.valueForKey("password") as? String

            txtUsername.text = ""
            txtPassword.text = ""

            //Transfers you to another view controller
            let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomePageViewController") as UIViewController

            self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        else
        {
            //Show Error Message
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "No such user"
            alert.message = "User does not exist"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Okay")
            alert.show()
        }

    }



}
```

This is the code used to show the username in the other view controller (just 1 line) which is "lblUsername.text = res.valueForKey("username") as? String
"

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Members")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


    let results:NSArray =  try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)


    index = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    let res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject

    super.viewDidLoad()
    circularImage(imageView1)
    lblUsername.text = res.valueForKey("username") as? String

    //Code to animate images
    imageView1.animationImages = [
        UIImage(named: Data.images[0])!,
        UIImage(named: Data.images[1])!,
        UIImage(named: Data.images[2])!,
        UIImage(named: Data.images[3])!,
        UIImage(named: Data.images[4])!,
        UIImage(named: Data.images[5])!
    ]

    imageView1.animationDuration = 15
    imageView1.startAnimating()


}
```

Comment: Where do you set the name to the label of the second view controller?

Comment: @dasdom at the second view controllers swift file

Comment: The please show the code because this is more relevant than the code you are showing right now.

Comment: @dasdom Sorry about that, added it

Comment: I don't see where you put the information inserted into the text fields into Core Data.